# Grunt Serve error, Running "compass:server" (compass) task Error: invalid option: --no-relative-assets

Tags: node.js, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I've distributed a project that was created using Yo and is an angularJS/HTML5 application. When distributing using GitHub all of users have been able to set up and run the app. But one user is getting the following error, I have never seen or experienced this myself but I need to help resolve this issue:

```
Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task
Error: invalid option: --no-relative-assets

Usage: compass compile [path/to/project] [path/to/project/src/file.sass ...] [options]

Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task Error: invalid option: --no-relative-assets

Usage: compass compile [path/to/project] [path/to/project/src/file.sass ...] [options]
```

I reinstalled the node modules using npm install and checked the sass and compass versions on the Mac, I got the following:

```
$ sass -v

Sass 3.4.9 (Selective Steve)

$ compass -v

Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2015 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass

$ gem install

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
chunky_png (1.3.3)
compass (1.0.1)
compass-core (1.0.1)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
ffi (1.9.6)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.10.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.5)
sass (3.4.9)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue here? I've never experienced this before and my versions of Compass and Sass are identical to the versions that my colleague has.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `npm update` on the project folder did the trick! I wasted hours on this problem!